# Can I persist table's and column's layout in javafx?

Tags: javafx

I want to save changes made by user on columns' size, order, width of different tables in my javafx application. Please Help 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: I have written this code for width changes and itz working now. column.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
          @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number oldWidth, Number
          newWidth) { 
          System.out.println("Width: " + oldWidth + " -> " + newWidth); }}); 
          ObservableList<TableColumn<Circuit, ?>> columnsO = tableView.getColumns(); 
          columnsO.forEach((columnW) -> { 
              columnW.setPrefWidth(columnW.getWidth());
          });

Comment: But I am not able to set column order in the same way. Please help

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include code, it is unreadable in comments. The [`getColumns()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#getColumns--) method in `TableView` returns a list of columns in their current order, so you can persist the order from that information and restore it when you start.

Comment: ohk, I will try that. Thanks for the suggestions.